# Flanneld not picking up the right network settings

Tags: centos, docker, kubernetes

I am running `Centos 7` with `Kubernetes`, `Docker`, `etcd` and `flanneld`. Currently I am seeing a problem with `Flanneld` which I can't seem to figure out.

I have setup etcd and configured the network. Following curl provides me the right output:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:4001/v2/keys/coreos.com/network/config
{"action":"get","node":{"key":"/coreos.com/network/config","value":"{ \"Network\": \"10.1.0.0/16\" }","modifiedIndex":1942,"createdIndex":1942}}
```

I have configured /etc/sysconfig/flanneld with the correct settings I believe:

```
FLANNEL_ETCD="http://127.0.0.1:4001"
FLANNEL_ETCD_KEY="/coreos.com/network"
```

I made sure `flanneld` starts at boot and starts without problems. However my flannel interface and docker interface get I believe wrong IP values:

```
4: flannel0: <POINTOPOINT,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1472 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 500
    link/none
    inet 0.0.98.0/16 scope global flannel0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN
    link/ether 56:84:7a:fe:97:99 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 0.0.98.1/24 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you're starting flannel BEFORE docker?
you should have something like

```
Requires=etcd2.service
Requires=flanneld.service
After=etcd2.service
After=flanneld.service
```

in your docker-tcp.socket Unit file